# How to animate falling ball in drag and drop? is it SetLocation(x,y) and thread?

Tags: java

```
for(int a=0;a<380;a++){
           try{
               Thread.sleep(5);
           }catch(Exception e){
               System.out.println(e);
           }
           item.setLocation(300, a);
       }
```

here is the process of my item moving downwards, but my problem is i cannot move it inch by inch.
item only shows up in (300,0) and (300,380), suppose to be 0,1,2,3,4----380 Help :((

Comment: Please provide more code. Do you want to move any image, panel or what? in swing, awt, javafx. Make your post clear.

Comment: What framework? Swing, AWT, GWT, SWT, JavaFX...?

Answer (score 0):

You're blocking the UI thread.

Basically, the caller running your rendering code (where you draw the ball) looks something like this:

```
while (true) {
    drawing = your_code();
    copy_drawing_to_GPU(drawing);
}
```

What this means, is that your code updates only show up *after* you return. Your for-loop runs entirely inside one "draw call" (it's usually called a frame, the origin of the term FPS - Frames Per Second - in gaming). Your code ends up doing this:

- Get called
- Sleep 5 ms
- Move 1 px
- Sleep 5ms
- Move 1 px
- ... repeat many times ..
- Return to caller
- Actually draw the object, **only once**

Hopefully this makes sense.

There's a couple solutions for this:

The best solution, and what is usually used in games, is using "delta times". Basically, you calculate the speed you want your ball to move at in pixels/millisecond, and the time elapsed since the last frame, and multiply those together to get how many pixels to move this frame. This is fairly easy to implement:

```
time = System.currentTimeMillis()
while (true) {
    drawing = update(System.currentTimeMillis() - time); // the "delta time"
    copy_to_GPU(drawing);
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Then, inside your code, instead of using a for loop you'd simply do:

```
item.setLocation(300, item.yPosition + deltaTime * item.ySpeed);
if (item.yPosition >= 380) {
    item.yPosition = 380;
    item.ySpeed = 0;
}
```

This correctly spreads your location updates over the correct number of frames. As a bonus, it also makes your program "lag-independent" - if your program starts lagging and takes a long time to render a frame, it will look choppy, but the ball will still be moving at the same speed (to an extent, you need more advanced techniques for serious lag).

The other option is to use a separate thread. This option kinda sucks, and I don't suggest using it.